# How to get entire input string in Lex and Yacc?

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

OK, so here is the deal.

In my language I have some commands, say

```
XYZ 3 5
GGB 8 9
HDH 8783 33
```

And in my Lex file

```
XYZ { return XYZ; }
GGB { return GGB; }
HDH { return HDH; }
[0-9]+ { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n  { return EOL; }
```

In my yacc file

```
start : commands
    ;

commands : command
         | command EOL commands
    ;

    command : xyz
            | ggb
            | hdh
    ;

    xyz : XYZ NUMBER NUMBER { /* Do something with the numbers */ }
       ;

    etc. etc. etc. etc.
```

My question is, how can I get the entire text

```
XYZ 3 5
GGB 8 9
HDH 8783 33
```

Into commands while still returning the NUMBERs?

Also when my Lex returns a STRING [0-9a-zA-Z]+, and I want to do verification on it's length, should I do it like

```
rule: STRING STRING { if (strlen($1) < 5 ) /* Do some shit else error */ }
```

or actually have a token in my Lex that returns different tokens depending on length?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your first question correctly, you can have semantic actions like

```
{ $$ = makeXYZ($2, $3); }
```

which will allow you to build the value of command as you want.

For your second question, the borders between lexical analysis and grammatical analysis and between grammatical analysis and semantic analysis aren't hard and well fixed.  Moving them is a trade-off between factors like easiness of description, clarity of error messages and robustness in presence of errors.  Considering the verification of string length, the likelihood of an error occurring is quite high and the error message if it is handled by returning different terminals for different length will probably be not clear.  So if it is possible -- that depend on the grammar -- I'd handle it in the semantic analysis phase, where the message can easily be tailored.

Answer (score 1):

If you arrange for your lexical analyzer (`yylex()`) to store the whole string in some variable, then your code can access it.  The communication with the parser proper will be through the normal mechanisms, but there's nothing that says you can't also have another variable lurking around (probably a file static variable - but beware multithreading) that stores the whole input line before it is dissected.

Comment: I guess maybe I wasn't that clear, but I have something like

HEADER

BLOCK1
STUFF
BLOCK1END

BLOCK2
STUFF
BLOCK2END

Where BLOCK1 and BLOCK2 match the same rule. What I need is the entire text of BLOCK1 at the time that I match BLOCK1. The simplest, but annoying way, is just to have all of the rules have a value of string, i.e. from my example

%type <sval> xyz

Then for every rule I would have to put

xyz: XYZ NUMBER NUMBER { $$ = "XYZ" + $2 + $3; }

Which overtime can get very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

As you use `yylval.ival` you already have `union` with `ival` field in your YACC source, like this:

```
%union {
    int ival;
}
```

Now you specify token type, like this:

```
%token <ival> NUMBER
```

So now you can access `ival` field simply for NUMBER token as `$1` in your rules, like

```
xyz : XYZ NUMBER NUMBER { printf("XYZ %d %d", $2, $3); }
```

For your second question I'd define union like this:

```
%union {
    char*   strval;
    int     ival;
}
```

and in you LEX source specify token types

```
%token <strval> STRING;
%token <ival> NUMBER;
```

So now you can do things like

```
foo : STRING NUMBER { printf("%s (len %d) %d", $1, strlen($1), $2); }
```

Comment: This gives a segfault on matches to string.